# Rails - News Feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Alright here's the trickiest question I've ever had to ask on StackOverflow.

My Web App allows creating a document. This document is automatically saved lets say ever couple of seconds.

Meanwhile, I want a news feed to lets users know what there friends are up to. So I created a observer model which after_create creates a news_feed type item.

Problem is this observer as is now will create a news_feed on ever save which is a huge firehose.

So I want to make it so the news_feed for this model is only injects per session or every X minutes. So I added a last_feeded_at column to the model.

Problem is when I try to update that field in the observer to mark it was feeded, that triggers the observer, which makes a mess of everything.

What's the best way to handle this? I'm open to all smart suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would not add an attribute to you Document model for this. You probably have something like this already:

```
class Document
  has_many :news_feeds, :order => 'created_at DESC'
end
```

In your callback (in Document model), just check when the last news_feed was created:

```
after_save :create_news_feed, :if => Proc.new { |doc| doc.news_feeds.first.created_at <= 10.minutes.ago }
```

This will only call `create_news_feed` if the last news_feed was created at least 10 minutes ago.

Comment: Just noticed your session requirement. Add an `attr_accessor :session_id` to your Document model and store that value with each new_feed record you create. Update the `:if` statement accordingly.

Comment: The OP wanted a news feed per session. Why not base the creation of the news feed on session rather than age?

Comment: Interesting, I was trying to do all this in the OBserver to keep it isolated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that when the user finishes editing they perform a final save? Define a attr_accessor, draft, which is sent as a parameter from the controller when handling request.js ajax saves. I don't see need for an observer really; just put it in the model.

```
attr_accessor :draft
after_save :log_unless_draft

def log_unless_draft
  unless draft.eql?(true)
    log_event.new(...
```

By the way, I don't understand why after_create is even triggering, given these aren't new_record?s beyond the first save.

Comment: To add a little more color. When a user clicks New Note, a Note is created and then the user is redirected to the note to start typing.. I don't want a news feed item at that time bec the Note Title has not yet been set. Which is why I only want to feed it once the title is note Untitled....

Comment: Also, there is no final save, it's more like Google Docs, the note is auto saving to the server (DEF UPDATE) on a timer and based on user activity. It's those saves that are flooding the feed and which I want to manage. Does that make sense?

Comment: Makes sense about the flooding though google docs does have a (final) save button; personally I think it would be bad interface design not to. Users will expect to save when they're finished and this would be the ideal time to log to the feed.

Comment: When I say "final" save I mean the save that the user interacts with that doesn't take place in the background; that is the floppy disk icon and file>save option.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create your NewsFeed object using this kind of logic

```
def find_or_create_feed
  if session[:news_feed].nil?
    NewsFeed.new
  else
    NewsFeed.find(session[:news_feed])
  end
end
```

that way, you can return the same `NewsFeed` object for an entire session. If you want to get fancy and expire it, do a sweep of the `news_feeds` table periodically to remove feeds over a given age.

Comment: @ Steve, thanks, but where would this live? Can you give a little more context around the use case? real excited to learn a smarter way to do what I'm trying to do. My code is getting messy! thanks

Comment: Well, it's your app, but I assume you have a controller that, from what you describe, handles the user interaction around creating and editing a document. Again, just from your description, it would seem you want to create a news feed when the document is accessed for the first time in a given session. So, I guess I would say hit it in a before_filter and assign the result to an instance variable so your view can display it. Or... it's possible I've missed your intent for this feature.

Comment: The controller should only perform 1 action on a model, e.g. save an update for Document. The Document model should then perform whatever dependent actions there are.

Comment: @Ariejan: Although you can strive to observe the LoD, controllers are constantly making information from disparate models -- sometimes unrelated -- available to their views. I would advocate for clarity of code.